# Assign the values for an array in Ada

Tags: arrays, variables, ada

I'm approaching the Ada language. I wrote this simple program that loops over an array and increments every single value, but the compiler gives me an error of type:

```
hello.adb:8:07: left hand side of assignment must be a variable
```

The program in question is this:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure hello is
type myArrayDefinition is array (1 .. 10) of integer;
myArray : constant myArrayDefinition := (1 => 3, others => 2);
begin
   for A in 1 .. 10 loop
     myArray(A) := myArray(A) + 1;
   end loop;
end hello;
```

Could anyone help me to understand the problem?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. `myArray` isn't a variable, it's a constant.

Comment: Just in case you have experience with some other language: an array object in Ada is not a reference, it is a true object. As noted, yours is constant, and then is constant as a whole. That's true for other objects as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify the value of a constant.  There are no special problems related to modifying the values of arrays.

Comment: IOW: The compiler *could* have said: "The target of an assignment must be a variable, not a constant."